# How to get the users who are not associated with any Identity Providers in Keycloak

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I'm able to get the users who are associated with Identity provider in keycloak, using endpoint `<keycloak_base_url>/auth/admin/realms/<realm_name>/users?idpAlias=<identity_provider_alias>`.

But here what I need is the opposite. I need all the users who is not associated with any of the identity provider.

[image]

Is their any way to get those users ?

Comment: i think you can't do as required. but you can get all users and filter the result.

Comment: You mean, get all the users first then remove the users who are associated with any identity provider. Correct ??

Comment: yes. keycloak caches  the users. that's why db traffic might not effect much.